# Load cache with predicate

Tags: ignite

I have a cache with many types in it. I am running pure Java nodes. I load the cache at start up before deploying services. The cache is backed by CacheJdbcPojoStore. I am using Ignite 1.8.

When I load with null predicate, everything works fine. All types and their instances are loaded in to memory. When I load with a predicate however, I get the following error. The curious thing is that on windows, the error does not occur and the predicate works fine. On Linux though, it fails. What could possibly be going wrong here?

The cache load code. ServiceStatus and ServiceMetric are just two of my pojo types backed by my database.

```
        log.info("Local load cache started.");
        cache.localLoadCache(new IgniteBiPredicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Object key, Object value) {
                // include by default, exclude explicitly

                // no service status before today
                if (value instanceof ServiceStatus) {
                    if (((ServiceStatus)value).getLastUpdated().before(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()))){
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // no service metrics before today
                if (value instanceof ServiceMetric) {
                    if (((ServiceMetric)value).getLastUpdated().before(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()))){
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }, null);
        log.info("Local load cache finished.");
```

The error.

[ERROR] 2017-01-30 13:01:28.913 [main] ServiceGrid - Failed with exception.
javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException: Failed to load cache: D9Cache
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.loadCache(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:847) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:512) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:497) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.localLoadCache(IgniteCacheProxy.java:413) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at com.nmf.model.persistence.CacheUtil.loadCache(CacheUtil.java:87) ~[shared-data-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.nmf.grid.ServiceGrid.main(ServiceGrid.java:75) [dragon9-service-grid-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed resolve class for ID: 292145121
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:696) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1491) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:637) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:142) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.loadEntry(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:528) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.access$300(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:94) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$4.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:501) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$4.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:497) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter$3.apply(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:528) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore$1.call(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:462) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore$1.call(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:429) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Class definition was not found at marshaller cache and local file. [id=292145121, file=/tmp/ignite/work/marshaller/292145121.classname]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.className(MarshallerContextImpl.java:218) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:174) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:680) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1491) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:637) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:142) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.loadEntry(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:528) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.access$300(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:94) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$4.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:501) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$4.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:497) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter$3.apply(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:528) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore$1.call(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:462) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore$1.call(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:429) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_111]

Comment: What is the type of the key? What is its type in Java and in database?

Comment: The key is a pojo that just contains a long field called id. This maps to a bigint column in the database, also called id.

Comment: Do you have this class on classpath? Does the issue exist if it's deployed explicitely there?

Comment: Yes, class is on the classpath for sure. I can directly copy the deployment from my windows machine to the linux machine, and it will stop working. If I remove the load predicate, then it works fine on both environments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure something changes when you move. I would also recommend to convert anonymous class to static class, so that you know for sure what is serialized and what is not. When implemented as anonymous class, filter can pick up smth unexpected that causes this error.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried static class also, even removing all the predicate logic, just return true. Same behaviour. Works on windows environment, not on my linux environment. I am running out of guesses on what the difference can be between these two environments.

Comment: Fixed. Something odd with how the manifest is read for the classpath I think. Seems like the manifest paths are relative to start location on linux but relative to jar location on windows???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional information, it's hard to advise but you can check if it is reproducible with cache.withKeepBinary(). Also, try to bounce the whole cluster. It's strange that the case stands only for Linux.

Comment: Definitely I have bounced the cluster many times. But I will try .withKeepBinary() Thanks.

Comment: I tried withKeepBinary() but this does not work. I think the windows vs linux thing is a red herring. I actually think this might be a race condition with the CacheJdbcPojoStore. My database is on the same host when running linux, but when running windows, the database is in the cloud, so the read times will be longer. I am suspicious about this error: [main] CacheJdbcPojoStore - Runnable tasks outlived thread pool executor service [owner=CacheJdbcPojoStore, tasks=[java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@46d9aec8, java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@14379273,

Comment: also there are many files here, with class names that I would expect, however clearly the one mentioned in the error message is not there  /tmp/ignite/work/marshaller

Comment: perhaps something to do with case sensitivity between lunix and windows?

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this issue which (in the interests of time) led me away from using predicates at all. On loading the cache when using predicates I would *sometimes* receive the exception you have noted above. I observed this on both Linux and windows, however it was not consistent. Sometimes the cache would load, sometimes not. As I said i was pushed for time so went with the assumption it was a race condition somewhere in the Ignite code that's running the predicate and worked around the issue.

If any Ignite experts can shed further light on a potential source of the issue I would be happy to help where possible.

--UPDATE --
I've worked around the issue by "warming" the binary marshaller before attempting to load date from the backing store (which was resulting in the file not found error)

So what I do is along the following lines:

```
 IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("my-cache");
 warmBinaryMarshaller(cache);
 cache.localLoadCache(cache, new MyPredicate(), (Object[])null);
```

...

```
private static void warmBinaryMarshaller(IgniteCache cache) throws Exception
{
    final IgniteCache transientCache = cache.withSkipStore();
    try{
        CacheKey key = new CacheKey();
        CacheEntity entity = CacheEntity(); 
        key.setId(0);
        entity.setId(0);
        transientCache.put(key, entity);
        transientCache.remove(key);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
     }
}
```

...

I can then load the object from my database successfully

Comment: Once you make it to 50 points, please make your statement a "Comment" (it's a good one), because that's what it is; it's not an "Answer" as it stands.

Comment: This has got to be a race condition. On a certain machine in the office, this problem never happens. Now for the first time I am running the same code version from my laptop at home, and the issue occurs.

Comment: It appears to me that the thread responsible for writing the type name to file has not completed it's work for all types before the GridDhtCacheAdapter tries to load the entry via the BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialise()